# Optimizing MYSQL Configuration

Tags: mysql, performance, mysqltuner

**I used MYSQLTUNER on my 1GB RAM Server. Here is the Output:-**

```
-------- General Statistics --------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.5.54-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
[OK] Operating on 32-bit architecture with less than 2GB RAM

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +Archive -BDB -Federated +InnoDB -ISAM -NDBCluster
[--] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 17)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 15M (Tables: 142)
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 1K (Tables: 14)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 142

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 8h 34m 20s (18K q [0.588 qps], 1K conn, TX: 307M, RX: 2M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 82% / 18%
[--] Total buffers: 240.0M global + 2.7M per thread (151 max threads)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 645.8M (64% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (57/18K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 17% (27/151)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 64.0M/138.0K
[!!] Key buffer hit rate: 88.5% (1K cached / 149 reads)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 67.8% (7K cached / 10K selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 1K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 6724
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 24% (1K on disk / 7K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 98% (28 created / 1K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 53% (368 open / 682 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 4% (46/1K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (12K immediate / 12K locks)
[OK] InnoDB data size / buffer pool: 15.2M/128.0M

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Enable the slow query log to troubleshoot bad queries
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
Variables to adjust:
    join_buffer_size (> 128.0K, or always use indexes with joins)
```

**And here is my MYSQL.conf file**

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
# bind-address      = 127.0.0.1

#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer      = 64M
max_allowed_packet  = 64M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 16
join_buffer_size    = 1M
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 20
table_cache            = 100
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 8M
query_cache_size        = 64M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Please provide me your expert advice to tune my MYSQL DB Performance
Please provide me your expert advice to tune my MYSQL DB Performance

Answer (score 0):

Are you facing any issues with current state of configuration?

Some generic recommendations :-
1) enable log_bin , if you need reduce your dataloss in case of crash
2) Set Server_id, in future you might need for replication setup, doesn't harm if you assign it in advance.
3) Reduce Key buffer size to default
4) Enable slow_query_log with 1-2 second of long_query_time value.
This will be helpful for troubleshooting performance issues related to bad queries.

Note : even if your server perforce well running this script will always suggest you to have few things change. Tuning is required when you are facing any performance issue. Above changes which i have mentioned are basic and some i would say you must follow for every server (like log_bin, server_id, slow queries) but each has its own downside like space consumption, bit of io consumption which may very case to case.

Are you facing any performance issue?

Hope this helps.

Comment: The main thing that needs tuning now is the slow queries.  So, find them, then ask for help.